# Design camunda generic flows that work for all tenants

Tags: java, spring, camunda

We are designing a workflow engine for multiple tenants. Tenants are for e-commerce stores of different product brands. So the number of tenants will be ever increasing and will be high in the near future.

Because of these reasons, we are thinking of designing generic flows that work for all tenants. And in these generic flows, before and after every task, we are trying to configure execution hooks for each tenant. We should be able to add logic for these hooks in runtime.

Is this approach correct? Is it possible to implement these hooks and add logic during runtime without deployments? Please help.

Comment: You can register a custom JobHandler.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the `ExternalTask-Pattern`. There you can integrate your own code without deploying it beforehand.

The ExternalTask-Pattern is explained here: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.10/user-guide/process-engine/external-tasks/

And an example for an implementation is here: https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/quick-start/service-task/